unable to insert the metadata while uploading the gridfs file upload
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const { GridFsStorage } = require('multer-gridfs-storage');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const router = express.Router();

let gfs;

// Establish connection to MongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dropurfiles', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

mongoose.connection.once('open', () => {
  gfs = Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');

  // Ensure the index on the metadata.ReciverID field
  mongoose.connection.db.collection('uploads.files').createIndex({ 'metadata.ReciverID': 1 }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error creating index:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Index created:', result);
    }
  });
});

// Use body-parser middleware to parse JSON data
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());

// Middleware to handle file uploads and extract ReciverID
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
  url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dropurfiles',
  options: { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  file: (req, file) => {
    const reciverId = req.reciverId; // Extract ReciverID from the custom middleware
    return {
      filename: file.originalname,
      bucketName: 'uploads',
      metadata: { "ReciverID": reciverId || null } // Add ReciverID to metadata
    };
  }
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

// Custom middleware to extract ReciverID before handling file uploads
router.post('/upload', (req, res, next) => {
  // Extract ReciverID from the request body
  req.reciverId = req.body.ReciverID;
  
  // Log the extracted ReciverID
  console.log('ReciverID from request body:', req.reciverId);

  // Call the next middleware or route handler
  next();
}, upload.array('files', 5), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.files || req.files.length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No files uploaded' });
    }

    // Handle file upload success
    res.status(201).json({ files: req.files });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error during file upload:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});


router.get('/files/:filename', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = await gfs.files.findOne({ filename: req.params.filename });
    if (!file || file.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: 'No file exists' });
    }

    const readstream = gfs.createReadStream(file.filename);
    readstream.pipe(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;


Im not able to insert Reciverid in the metadata i have tried multiple types but it returns only null when i upload or post from post man and i have also used application/json in the header and if someone has done this please help me to reslove
slove the metadata to upload the reciver id field without null
